# SSH "Read from socket failed: Connection reset by peer" on Ubuntu AWS AMI for 16.04 Xenial

Tags: ssh, amazon-ec2

I get `Read from socket failed: Connection reset by peer` when I ssh to an EC2 Instance running AMI `ubuntu/images/hvm-ssd/ubuntu-xenial-16.04-amd64-server-20160516.1` in `us-east-1` (ami id `ami-13be557e`).  [This Unix StackExchange Post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/119256/94258) suggests there may be a permission problem on the server and suggests checking `/var/log/auth.log` on a server which I cannot ssh into.

I found the AMI via the [AMI locator](https://cloud-images.ubuntu.com/locator/ec2/), since Amazon's official Ubuntu image is 14.04 as of this writing.

```
$ ssh -vvv -i ~/Downloads/pete.pem ubuntu@123.123.123.123

OpenSSH_6.2p2, OSSLShim 0.9.8r 8 Dec 2011
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh_config line 20: Applying options for *
debug1: /etc/ssh_config line 102: Applying options for *
debug2: ssh_connect: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to 107.21.86.158 [107.21.86.158] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug3: Incorrect RSA1 identifier
debug3: Could not load "/Users/pete/Downloads/pete.pem" as a RSA1 public key
debug1: identity file /Users/pete/Downloads/pete.pem type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/pete/Downloads/pete.pem-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.2
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu1
debug1: match: OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu1 pat OpenSSH*
debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug3: load_hostkeys: loading entries for host "107.21.86.158" from file "/Users/pete/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 0 keys
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
Read from socket failed: Connection reset by peer
```

It seems the ["Incorrect RSA1 Identififer" debug3 messages are a red herring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12449626/trying-to-use-rsa-keys-to-ssh-into-ec2-getting-incorrect-rsa1-identifier-pe/15563793#15563793).

Note my security group & networking is setup such that I can see the machine.  `nmap` reports the box is listening on port 22:

```
$ nmap -sV 107.21.86.158

Starting Nmap 7.00 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2016-06-08 12:06 MDT
Nmap scan report for ec2-107-21-86-158.compute-1.amazonaws.com (107.21.86.158)
Host is up (0.059s latency).
Not shown: 997 filtered ports
PORT    STATE  SERVICE VERSION
22/tcp  open   ssh     OpenSSH 7.2p2 Ubuntu 4ubuntu1 (Ubuntu Linux; protocol 2.0)
Service Info: OS: Linux; CPE: cpe:/o:linux:linux_kernel

Service detection performed. Please report any incorrect results at https://nmap.org/submit/ .
Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 5.72 seconds
```

Comment: Try this [Duplicate](http://superuser.com/questions/1082529/strange-ssh-connection-issue/1082542)

Comment: @Jakuje I have no way of changing the MTU in `/etc/init.d/interfaces` on the EC2 instance which is the remote server.  I would need to login to the instance to do that.  I think you're suggesting [AMI ubuntu/images/hvm-ssd/ubuntu-xenial-16.04-amd64-server-20160516.1](https://console.aws.amazon.com/ec2/home?region=us-east-1#launchAmi=ami-f652979b) has a bug.

Comment: You do that on you client.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out the IT department of my company had a network equipment misconfigured somehow.  Eventually it was fixed and now SSH works fine.